# Updating Vue instance disables certain element

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I am creating a roster in which assignment can be made using Vue. If I assign a person to a particular shift, then he is removed from all the preferences and we would no longer be able to navigate through different options. The close moves the preference up by 1 and the prev icon moves it down by 1 and tick makes the assignment. Have a look at the code [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amahajan/3zxgvf17/9/).

Now when an assignment is done then a delete operation is carried out. And after that, entire Vue is force updated. This delete operation disables the preference list navigation in all other table cells.Why this disabling occurs? Is there any solution to that. Also can Vue force Update be avoided?

```
 $('.assign').click(function() {
   app.assignNurse($(this));
   app.$forceUpdate();


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update the following line in your code.

```
$(document).on('click','.close',function() {
       const curr = $(this).parent();
       //console.log(curr.next());
       curr.next().show();
       $(this).parent().hide();
       //$('.selection2').show();
       //prevObj = curr;

    });
 $(document).on('click','.assign',function() {
            console.log("ss");
       app.assignNurse($(this));            
    });

$(document).on('click','.repeat',function(){
  $(this).parent().hide();
  //console.log($(this).parent().prev('div'));
  $(this).parent().prev('div').show();

  //$(this).parent().remove();

});
```

**issue is coming because you are creating element dynamically so jquery simple click event can't work on the element which is created dynamically so you need to write click event like this.**

Here is updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/voy6bnrc/) link you can check here its working perfectly.